# Saving data to AWS RDS Postgres SQL from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm building a lambda function that is supposed to save some data into my Postgres database, which is in AWS RDS.

I'm using NodeJS typescript and the function is kinda working, but in a strange way.

I made an API Gateway so I can POST data to the URL to the lambda process it and save it, the thing is, when I POST something for the first 2 times, the function doesn't save anything in the database, but when I try posting a third time, the data sent in the first try gets saved, an then the fourth saves the second try's data.

And doesn't matter what I pass into the callback function of the handler it always gives me a response like:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Can any of you guys help me with this strange problem?

Thanks

My code to save the data in Postgres is this:

```
pool.connect((err, cli, release) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error acquiring client.", err.stack);
    } else {
      cli.query(query, (er, res) => {
        release();
        if (er) {
          console.error("Error executing query.", err.stack);
        } else {
          console.log(res.rows);
          cb(null, res.rows);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: anything useful in the CloudWatch logs?

Comment: Nothing useful, just logs about every request I make, it seems to receive the correct data every time, but it seems like it's not being saved, It seems o store the data in some kind of queue and than after receiving more requests it saves the old data.

Comment: Apparently there's an exception in part you are not showing (`Internal server error`)

Comment: Actually I found another thing that could hint to the actual problem that is the response from the server 

HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 02 Aug 2018 20:37:58 GMT
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront

{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}

Comment: It's giving me the "Error From CloudFront" X-cache header, and I can't find out why is that happening